# Hierarchical Attention Network - model.fit generates error 'ValueError: Input dimension mis-match'

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, attention-model

For background, I am referring to the [Hierarchical Attention Network](https://richliao.github.io/supervised/classification/2016/12/26/textclassifier-HATN/) used for sentiment classification.

**For code**: my full code is posted below, but it is just simple revision of the original code posted by the author on the link above.  And I explain my changes below.
**For training data**: [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/data)
**For word embeddings**: this is the Glove embedding [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip)
**Key config**: Keras 2.0.9, Scikit-Learn 0.19.1, Theano 0.9.0

The original code posted in the link above takes a 3D shape input, i.e., (review, sentence, word). And the attention mechanism is applied to sentence, and also words. So it had two attention components, as you can see in the fourth code block on the webpage.

I would like to change it to one that takes only a **2D shape input**. I do this by

1. changing the input shape and input embedding matrix (see inline comment in my code below)
2. changing the model building part by removing the sentence attention component, keeping only the word attention component (see inline comment in my code below)

However, the code generates an error when 'model.fit' is called. I post the complete code and error below.

**CODE**:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import os

from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer, text_to_word_sequence
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.layers import Embedding, GRU, Bidirectional, TimeDistributed
from keras.models import Model

from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras import initializers

MAX_SENT_LENGTH = 100
MAX_NB_WORDS = 20000
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100
VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.2


def clean_str(string):
    """
    Tokenization/string cleaning for dataset
    Every dataset is lower cased except
    """
    string = re.sub(r"\\", "", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\'", "", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\"", "", string)
    return string.strip().lower()


#replace this to your own file path
data_train = pd.read_csv('/home/zz/Work/wop/data/sentiment/labeledTrainData_small.tsv', sep='\t')
print(data_train.shape)

labels = []
texts = []

for idx in range(data_train.review.shape[0]):
    text = BeautifulSoup(data_train.review[idx])
    text = clean_str(text.get_text().encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii'))
    texts.append(text)
    labels.append(data_train.sentiment[idx])

tokenizer = Tokenizer(nb_words=MAX_NB_WORDS)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)

##################################
# Change 1. The input shape is now 2D (sentence, words) instead of 3D
##################################
data = np.zeros((len(texts), MAX_SENT_LENGTH), dtype='int32')
for i, content in enumerate(texts):
    wordTokens = text_to_word_sequence(content)
    k = 0
    for _, word in enumerate(wordTokens):
        if k < MAX_SENT_LENGTH and tokenizer.word_index[word] < MAX_NB_WORDS:
            data[i, k] = tokenizer.word_index[word]
            k = k + 1
##################################

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print('Total %s unique tokens.' % len(word_index))

labels = to_categorical(np.asarray(labels))
print('Shape of data tensor:', data.shape)
print('Shape of label tensor:', labels.shape)

indices = np.arange(data.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(indices)
data = data[indices]
labels = labels[indices]
nb_validation_samples = int(VALIDATION_SPLIT * data.shape[0])

x_train = data[:-nb_validation_samples]
y_train = labels[:-nb_validation_samples]
x_val = data[-nb_validation_samples:]
y_val = labels[-nb_validation_samples:]

print('Number of positive and negative reviews in traing and validation set')
print(y_train.sum(axis=0))
print(y_val.sum(axis=0))

#replace with your own embedding file path
GLOVE_DIR = "/home/zz/Work/data/glove.6B"
embeddings_index = {}
f = open(os.path.join(GLOVE_DIR, 'glove.6B.100d.txt'))
for line in f:
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_index[word] = coefs
f.close()

print('Total %s word vectors.' % len(embeddings_index))

embedding_matrix = np.random.random((len(word_index) + 1, EMBEDDING_DIM))
for word, i in word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        # words not found in embedding index will be all-zeros.
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

# building Hierachical Attention network
embedding_matrix = np.random.random((len(word_index) + 1, EMBEDDING_DIM))
for word, i in word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        # words not found in embedding index will be all-zeros.
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

embedding_layer = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=MAX_SENT_LENGTH,
                            trainable=True,
                            mask_zero=True)


class AttLayer(Layer):
def __init__(self, attention_dim,**kwargs):
    self.init = initializers.get('normal')
    self.supports_masking = True
    self.attention_dim = attention_dim
    super(AttLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    assert len(input_shape) == 3
    self.W = K.variable(self.init((input_shape[-1], self.attention_dim)))
    self.b = K.variable(self.init((self.attention_dim,)))
    self.u = K.variable(self.init((self.attention_dim, 1)))
    self.trainable_weights = [self.W, self.b, self.u]
    super(AttLayer, self).build(input_shape)

def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
    return None

def call(self, x, mask=None):
    # size of x :[batch_size, sel_len, attention_dim]
    # size of u :[batch_size, attention_dim]
    # uit = tanh(xW+b)
    uit = K.tile(K.expand_dims(self.W, axis=0), (K.shape(x)[0], 1, 1))
    uit = tf.matmul(x, uit)
    uit = K.tanh(K.bias_add(uit, self.b))
    ait = K.dot(uit, self.u)
    ait = K.squeeze(ait, -1)

    ait = K.exp(ait)

    if mask is not None:
        # Cast the mask to floatX to avoid float64 upcasting in theano
        ait *= K.cast(mask, K.floatx())
    ait /= K.cast(K.sum(ait, axis=1, keepdims=True) + K.epsilon(), K.floatx())
    ait = K.expand_dims(ait)
    weighted_input = x * ait
    output = K.sum(weighted_input, axis=1)

    return output

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], input_shape[-1])

#################################################
# Change 2. The model contains only one attention block now
#################################################
sentence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SENT_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sentence_input)
l_lstm = Bidirectional(GRU(100, return_sequences=True))(embedded_sequences)
l_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(200))(l_lstm)
l_att = AttLayer(100)(l_dense)
############################################

preds = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(l_att)
model = Model(sentence_input, preds)

#### clone the model #### Line X
model_copy = clone_model(model)

plot_model(model, to_file="model.png")
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print("model fitting - Hierachical attention network")
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
          nb_epoch=10, batch_size=50,verbose=2)
```

**ERROR**: the last line of the code generates an error trace of:

```
Epoch 1/10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zz/Programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 884, in __call__
    self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
ValueError: Input dimension mis-match. (input[0].shape[1] = 50, input[1].shape[1] = 100)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zz/Work/wop/code/python/src/3rdparty/han/textClassfierHATT2D.py", line 187, in <module>
    nb_epoch=10, batch_size=50,verbose=2)
  File "/home/zz/Programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1631, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/home/zz/Programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1213, in _fit_loop
    outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/home/zz/Programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 1223, in __call__
    return self.function(*inputs)
  File "/home/zz/Programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 898, in __call__
    storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
  File "/home/zz/Programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gof/link.py", line 325, in raise_with_op
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
  File "/home/zz/Programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 692, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/zz/Programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 884, in __call__
    self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
ValueError: Input dimension mis-match. (input[0].shape[1] = 50, input[1].shape[1] = 100)
Apply node that caused the error: Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}(InplaceDimShuffle{x,0}.0, Elemwise{Cast{float32}}.0)
Toposort index: 459
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, row), TensorType(float32, matrix)]
Inputs shapes: [(1, 50), (50, 100)]
Inputs strides: [(200, 4), (400, 4)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[Sum{axis=[1], acc_dtype=float64}(Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}.0)]]

HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.
HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

I would really appreciate some advice on this, many thanks in advance!

Comment: I've played with `AttLayer` and found that the problem is related to `ait = K.squeeze(ait, -1)` and I am still finding a solution.

Comment: Many thanks for the update, I'd been keen to hear it

Comment: In `uit = K.tanh(K.bias_add(K.dot(x, self.W), self.b))`, you want your x of shape`[batch_size, sel_len, attention_dim]` dot W of shape `[input_shape[-1], self.attention_dim]` and then get result of shape `[self.attention_dim,]`. How could that be?

Comment: sorry I really cannot answer that. I am using third party code as a black box...

Comment: That's fine. You can try my answer with tensorflow 1.12.0 backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the referenced tutorial, it choose to use `theano` instead of `tensorflow` because the behavior of `dot` in `tensorflow` is different from that in `numpy`. But I am not familiar with `theano` so it's hard for me to make it work correctly by using `theano` backend. I rather use a series of operations to mimic the behavior of `dot` in `numpy`. Following I've changed the `K.dot` to a series of operations.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer, text_to_word_sequence
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.layers import Embedding, GRU, Bidirectional, TimeDistributed, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras import initializers

class AttLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, attention_dim, **kwargs):
        self.init = initializers.get('normal')
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.attention_dim = attention_dim
        super(AttLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 3
        self.W = K.variable(self.init((input_shape[-1], self.attention_dim)))
        self.b = K.variable(self.init((self.attention_dim,)))
        self.u = K.variable(self.init((self.attention_dim, 1)))
        self.trainable_weights = [self.W, self.b, self.u]
        super(AttLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
        return None

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        # size of x :[batch_size, sel_len, attention_dim]
        # size of u :[batch_size, attention_dim]
        # uit = tanh(xW+b)
        uit = K.tile(K.expand_dims(self.W, axis=0), (K.shape(x)[0], 1, 1))
        uit = tf.matmul(x, uit)
        uit = K.tanh(K.bias_add(uit, self.b))
        ait = K.dot(uit, self.u)
        ait = K.squeeze(ait, -1)

        ait = K.exp(ait)

        if mask is not None:
            # Cast the mask to floatX to avoid float64 upcasting in theano
            ait *= K.cast(mask, K.floatx())
        ait /= K.cast(K.sum(ait, axis=1, keepdims=True) + K.epsilon(), K.floatx())
        ait = K.expand_dims(ait)
        weighted_input = x * ait
        output = K.sum(weighted_input, axis=1)

        return output

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], input_shape[-1])

    # https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5401
    # solve the problem of keras.models.clone_model
    # and model.save_weights, model.load_weights
    def get_config(self):
        config = {'attention_dim': self.attention_dim}
        base_config = super(AttLayer, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

Also `compute_mask` now returns `None` because there is no `sel_len` axis in `AttLayer`'s output.

Following is a script validating that the two operations are equivalent:

```
B = 8
S = 100
E = 200
A = 50
X = np.random.randn(B, S, E)
W = np.random.randn(E, A)
np_result = np.dot(X, W) #shape correct

X_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float64)
W_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float64)

tf_dot = tf.matmul(X_ph, 
                   tf.tile(
                           tf.expand_dims(W_ph, axis=0),
                           (K.shape(X_ph)[0], 1, 1)))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf_result = sess.run(tf_dot,
                         feed_dict = {X_ph:X, W_ph:W})

print(np.allclose(np_result, tf_result)) #True
```

Training history(I set `batch_size` as 8):

```
Train on 20000 samples, validate on 5000 samples
Epoch 1/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1247s 62ms/step - loss: 0.4203 - acc: 0.8044 - val_loss: 0.3520 - val_acc: 0.8468
Epoch 2/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 985s 49ms/step - loss: 0.2344 - acc: 0.9070 - val_loss: 0.3411 - val_acc: 0.8586
Epoch 3/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 996s 50ms/step - loss: 0.0982 - acc: 0.9628 - val_loss: 0.4474 - val_acc: 0.8512
Epoch 4/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 966s 48ms/step - loss: 0.0285 - acc: 0.9904 - val_loss: 0.7837 - val_acc: 0.8408
Epoch 5/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 912s 46ms/step - loss: 0.0179 - acc: 0.9936 - val_loss: 1.0177 - val_acc: 0.8440
Epoch 6/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 910s 45ms/step - loss: 0.0105 - acc: 0.9963 - val_loss: 1.0635 - val_acc: 0.8418
Epoch 7/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 909s 45ms/step - loss: 0.0101 - acc: 0.9964 - val_loss: 1.0966 - val_acc: 0.8372
Epoch 8/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 909s 45ms/step - loss: 0.0057 - acc: 0.9981 - val_loss: 1.2678 - val_acc: 0.8392
Epoch 9/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 910s 46ms/step - loss: 0.0077 - acc: 0.9974 - val_loss: 1.2166 - val_acc: 0.8258
Epoch 10/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 910s 46ms/step - loss: 0.0056 - acc: 0.9985 - val_loss: 1.4640 - val_acc: 0.8204
```

Comment: Thank you I am grateful. A couple of questions though: (1) in 'uit = tf.matmul(x, uit)' is tf 'tensorflow'? (2) I replaced it with 'numpy.matmul', but getting error saying ' line 148, in call
    uit = K.tile(K.expand_dims(self.W, axis=0), (K.shape(x)[0], 1, 1))
  File "/home/zz/Programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 971, in tile
    if n.ndim == 0:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndim' ---------- tensorflow implementation is fine and working but please allow me to test thoroughly as my previous experiments are all in theano.

Comment: Yes, actually I `import tensorflow as tf`.

Comment: @Ziqi I added the packages I've imported.

Comment: Is it easy to change it so that the models supports 'clone_model'? When I do this (adding it after 'model = Model(sentence_input, preds)', there is an error ''textClassfierHATT2D.py", ...
  .../keras/models.py", line 1558, in clone_model
    return _clone_functional_model(model, input_tensors=input_tensors)
  .../keras/models.py", line 1413, in _clone_functional_model
    new_layer = layer.__class__.from_config(layer.get_config())
  .../keras/engine/topology.py", line 1253, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Comment: @Ziqi Can you paste the full code in your problem description?

Comment: Yes, line added now. see 'Line X' in the original post. I tried a solution suggested here but it is not working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098566/typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-trainable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189813/discussion-between-ziqi-and-keineahnung2345).