# Problem in loading and compiling Keras model

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, keras

I trained a Keras model:

```
class CTCLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.loss_fn = keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        # Compute the training-time loss value and add it
        # to the layer using `self.add_loss()`.
        batch_len = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], dtype="int64")
        input_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[1], dtype="int64")
        label_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], dtype="int64")

        input_length = input_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")
        label_length = label_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")

        loss = self.loss_fn(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
        self.add_loss(loss)

        # At test time, just return the computed predictions
        return y_pred




def build_model():
    # Inputs to the model
    input_img = layers.Input(
        shape=(img_width, img_height, 4), name="image", dtype="float32"
    )
    labels = layers.Input(name="label", shape=(None,), dtype="float32")

    # First conv block
    x = layers.Conv2D(
        32,
        (3,3),
        activation="relu",
        kernel_initializer="he_normal",
        padding="same",
        name="Conv1",
    )(input_img)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="pool1")(x)

    # Second conv block
    x = layers.Conv2D(
        64,
        (3, 3),
        activation="relu",
        kernel_initializer="he_normal",
        padding="same",
        name="Conv2",
    )(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name="pool2")(x)


    # We have used two max pool with pool size and strides 2.
    # Hence, downsampled feature maps are 4x smaller. The number of
    # filters in the last layer is 64. Reshape accordingly before
    # passing the output to the RNN part of the model
    new_shape = ((img_width // 4), (img_height // 4) * 64)
    x = layers.Reshape(target_shape=new_shape, name="reshape")(x)
    x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense1")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)

    # RNNs
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1))(x)
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1))(x)

    # Output layer
    x = layers.Dense(len(characters) + 1, activation="softmax", name="dense2")(x)

    # Add CTC layer for calculating CTC loss at each step
    output = CTCLayer(name="ctc_loss")(labels, x)

    # Define the model
    model = keras.models.Model(
        inputs=[input_img, labels], outputs=output, name="ocr_model_v1"
    )
    # Optimizer
    opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
    # Compile the model and return
    model.compile(optimizer=opt)
    return model


# Get the model
model = build_model()
model.summary()


epochs = 100
early_stopping_patience = 10
# Add early stopping
early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor="val_loss", patience=early_stopping_patience, restore_best_weights=True
)

# Train the model
history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    validation_data=validation_dataset,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=[early_stopping],
)
# serialize model to JSON
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("model.h5")
```

But when I try to load it like this in another code:

```
# # load json and create model
json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json,custom_objects={'CTCLayer': CTCLayer})

# load weights into new model
model.load_weights("model.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
# Compile the model
model.compile(loss="ctc_loss",optimizer=opt)

# Get the prediction model by extracting layers till the output layer
prediction_model = keras.models.Model(
    model.get_layer(name="image").input, model.get_layer(name="dense2").output
)
prediction_model.summary()
```

And then evaluate it:

```
for batch in validation_dataset.take(1):
    batch_images = batch["image"]    
    prediction_model.evaluate(batch_images)
```

I get the following error:

```
    RuntimeError: You must compile your model before training/testing. Use `model.compile(optimizer, loss)`.
```

But I've already compiled my model. So what's wrong?

If all of this looks messy, in summary, I was basically trying to implement this [Keras tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/) and I can save the model but I can't load the model. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I shall note that I think one of the reasons I cannot use trivial methods to save and load the model is the fact that the model has a custom layer/loss function. (`CTCLayer`)

Answer (score 2):

```
prediction_model = keras.models.Model(
    model.get_layer(name="image").input, model.get_layer(name="dense2").output
)
# Optimizer
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam()
# Compile the model and return# Biên dịch mô hình
prediction_model.compile(optimizer=opt)
prediction_model.summary()

### Evaluate the model
loss = prediction_model.evaluate(validation_dataset)#(x_valid, y_valid, verbose=2)
```

This worked for me.
and you should see this [TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trainable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098566/typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-trainable)
there is a error in
`class CTCLayer(layers.Layer)`
however, I have been unsucessful in loading this model
https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/
it's bad in predicting
help me!

Answer (score 0):

https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/
[image]

error exactly is in here
each time you use trained model to predict, characters set will be loaded again; and split_data will return other result if ur characters set lacks something
in my case, my characters set lacks some characters (<24 characters) and maybe some numbers (3, 5, 6 for example)

update:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import string


class LabelCharacters(object):
    characters_set = ['0']
def __init__(self, characters_set=None):
    if characters_set:
        self.characters_set = characters_set
    self.characters_dic = {c: p for p, c in enumerate(characters_set)}
    self.char_to_num = layers.experimental.preprocessing.StringLookup(
        vocabulary=list(self.characters_set), mask_token=None)
    # Mapping integers back to original characters
    self.num_to_char = layers.experimental.preprocessing.StringLookup(
        vocabulary=self.char_to_num.get_vocabulary(), mask_token=None, invert=True)
    self.num_class = len(self.characters_set) + 1
    super().__init__()

# A utility function to decode the output of the network
def decode_batch_predictions(self, pred, max_length):
    input_len = np.ones(pred.shape[0]) * pred.shape[1]
    # Use greedy search. For complex tasks, you can use beam search
    results = keras.backend.ctc_decode(pred, input_length=input_len, greedy=True)[0][0][:, :max_length]
    # Iterate over the results and get back the text
    output_text = [tf.strings.reduce_join(self.num_to_char(res)).numpy().decode("utf-8") for res in results]
    return output_text

def encode_label(self, label):
    return self.char_to_num(tf.strings.unicode_split(label, input_encoding="UTF-8"))

def decode_label(self, label):
    try:
        return tf.strings.reduce_join(self.num_to_char(label)).numpy().decode("utf-8")
    except:
        return 'FAIL'

s = [z for z in string.ascii_uppercase]
zs = [z for z in range(10)]
s.extend(zs)

label_digit = LabelCharacters(characters_set = s)
##label_digit = LabelCharacters(characters_set=['{0}'.format(_) for _ in range(0, 10)]) `
```

label.py
and in main py file:

```
from label import label_digit
```

Comment: Okay, but how to fix this?

Comment: import string

characters = [z for z in string.ascii_uppercase];
zs = [z for z in range(10)];
characters.extend(zs);

Comment: and put it in other file, then import

Comment: This is a complex problem. Please edit your post with corrected code.

Comment: I have updated my answer; is there any thing more I can help; do u succeed?